# Changing Service Credentials remotely via Powershell

Tags: powershell

Ive trying to update the credentials on one service, which is installed on almost every client in the domain. Currently the service runs under LocalSystem and I want to switch in a domain-user. The user would be the same for all (client)-services, its just for restricting some privileges.
I already tried:

```
$cList = @(Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=***,DC=***,DC=local"| where { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=*** *" -and $_.Name}) |
Foreach-Object (GWMI win32_service -filter "name='<Service>'" -computer $cList.Name).change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"<Domain>\<User>","<PW>",$null,$null,$null)
```

there whenever i try

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "Name='***'" -computer *** -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).stopservice()
(Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "Name='***'" -computer *** -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).startservice()
```

i get:

```
 __GENUS          : 2
 __CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
 __SUPERCLASS     :
 __DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
 __RELPATH        :
 __PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
 __DERIVATION     : {}
 __SERVER         :
 __NAMESPACE      :
 __PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 15 
PSComputerName   :
```

which translate to "Wrong credentials to start as a service"
[docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/startservice-method-in-class-win32-service)

(same when invoking on a client)

sad thing is, it works on my own client

> ReturnValue      : 0

How to proceed or where am i wrong?

Comment: (i tried PS 5.1 and 7.2)

Comment: PLEASE do not post code/data/errors in the comments. they belong in your Question ... and need to be wrapped in code formatting markers to be easy to read. [*grin*]

Comment: Can be closed, I found the answer.
Windows sets the privilege to logon as a service if you assign the user manualy.
If you do it via this script you have to assign the user to the service AND grant him the privilege to logon as a service.